# Why is Natty's daily live build not updated daily anymore?

Tags: unity, compiz, 11.04, build

I thought the daily build on http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ would be updated daily, but the current build is 6 days old. I would love to try out Natty and Compiz Unity on a live USB-drive, but it's not much use if it's not updated.

Any reason why the build is so old? Does anybody know when it will be updated again?

Comment: Did you check their Launchpad page? Might find a clue there.

Answer (score 4):

The developers are currently [moving the default Python version from 2.6 to 2.7](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2010-December/000795.html), which involves rebuilding (and sometimes changing) a lot of applications that are written in Python or depend on it (e.g. for plugins, scripting, etc.).  I am running *Natty* on 1 machine, and currently part of this migration is done, but not all of it.  The result is that the latest version of several packages (that are already converted) can **not** be installed together with the latest version of some other packages (that have not been converted yet).  That also means that building an ISO fails, hence no new "daily" CDs.

*(To be sure somebody from the team that is responsible for building the ISOs should confirm this, but I'm pretty sure this is the main reason.)*

This may also happen in other cases where applications that are installed on de ISO depend on each other or on a common library, and have version mismatches.

Comment: Thank you, I'll just wait until they have completed the move to Python 2.7 then.